# S5 Phone and SD Card Encryption: Do I need to enter in password twice?

Tags: sd-card, encryption, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5. If I encrypt the phone and the SD card, presumably with the same PIN/password, do I need to enter in the PIN two times to access the SD card?

I see that encrypting the phone and SD card are two separate processes, but does that mean that I will need to decrypt the phone and the SD card separately every time I use an app or file that's on the SD card?

Answer (score 1):

No. I have that setup and you don't need to enter the password two times. Also when encrypting, android (at least my 4.2.2) does not let you use different passwords for Device and SD card.

One downside of having the phone encrypted is that Android forces you to use the encryption password in the screen lock. After encrypting the phone, you can't use pattern unlock. This has been reported [two years ago](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29468).

Comment: Thanks. What I really want to do is use a PIN, but from what I've read I have to use a password that's at least six characters, including one digit if I want to encrypt my S5.

Comment: Encrypting using a 4 digit password wouldn't provide any real security against a brute force (or even manual force) attack. I have a good password for the disk and SD card, and a PIN for the SIM card. The only time I have to enter both passwords is when I turn on the cellphone (first encryption, then PIN for the SIM card). The PIN for the SIM card is useless, that's why I save the contacts and messages on the device.